# React Router mapping over routes array always refetches on location changes - Memoizing possible?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/routes-array-example-ldvmv)

Hi, if I create an `array of routes` with React Router which has the HOC of `<MainRoute />` which wraps the actual `<Component /> with <Main/>`, on every path change `<Main/>` is getting remounted and hence the useEffect hook is getting recalled.

Is there a way to only remount the `<Component />` not `<Main/>` itself? Maybe some kind of memoization?

Mapping over `routes` is very convenient, however it seems to re-map everything on the location change which doesn't happen if I just hardcode every route like `<MainRoute path=.. component=.. />` inside the `<Switch />`.

Help highly appreciated,

Cheers

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Layout = styled.div`
  margin: auto;
  width: 0;
`;

const Main = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("API REQUEST - Called every time");
  }, []);

  return <Layout>{React.cloneElement(children, props)}</Layout>;
};

const MainRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        return (
          <Main path={rest.path}>
            <Component {...props} />
          </Main>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        {routes.map(({ path, component }) => (
          <MainRoute key={path} path={path} component={component} exact />
        ))}
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const Home = () => (
  <>
    Home <Link to="/other">Other</Link>
  </>
);
const Other = () => (
  <>
    Other <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  </>
);

const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Home },
  { path: "/other", component: Other }
];
```